# Having trouble building xv6 using QEMU

Tags: linux, virtualization, qemu

I followed all the instructions on [the following page](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2018/tools.html). And I installed QEMU and set the prefix to `/usr/local` on my machine.

I downloaded the `xv6-public` package into my `/home` directory. And I went to the directory and ran

```
make qemu
```

This does not execute and returns with the error message

> No protocol specified
>   (qemu-system-i386:18193): Gtk-WARNING: cannot open display: :0
>   Makefile:226: recipe for target 'qemu' failed
>   make: [qemu] Error 1

I changed the first line of the Makefile in `xv6-public` to include `qemu-system-i386` as follows:

```
QEMU=/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-i386
```

But I get the same error.
Can you please help me with this?